# How to get parameters with multipart form

Tags: java, forms, apache, multipart

```
<form method="post" action="/Project/vt" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
            <input type="text" name="tittle"/>
            <input type="file" name="image"/>
            <button type="submit">Confirm</button>
</form>
```

In this form, I have 2 inputs and I have to obtain both parameters. I know that using multipart I can't getParameter of tittle. I watched the next code from http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-fileupload//using.html:

```
Iterator<FileItem> iter = items.iterator();
while (iter.hasNext()) {
    FileItem item = iter.next();

    if (item.isFormField()) {
        processFormField(item);
    } else {
        processUploadedFile(item);
    }
}
```

I think that with this code, I can obtain both parameters (in the IF tittle and in the ELSE image) but I don't know how can I implement that code on my Manager Servlet because I don't know what is Iterator, items,  FileItem... I'm so lost in this moment.

Thank you !

Comment: Be more specific and we can help.